# The entity type is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

My ASP.NET application is working locally, but when I deploy it, I get the following error: "The entity type Usuario is not part of the model for the current context". I've tried every solution I found, but I couldn't get it work.

I think it can be something wrong in connection string because they are different ones to local database and remote database. This is the connection string in Web.Release.config file:

```
<add name="ModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source = tcp:ebmzszqsw8.database.windows.net,1433; Initial Catalog = {database_name}; User ID = {my_id}; Password={my_password};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

Comment: Compare both connection strings esp. for the metadata part. In the release version it is not complete.

Comment: Sorry for not reply yet. I'm new in Stack Overflow and I don't know how it works. About the connection string, it's the way we tell the system to search the metadata files in every folder. It's important I don't know the remote files location.